# Use Javascript to built array from data-value of <li class = 'bu'>

Tags: javascript, html

Build array of data-value from  not successful

I have many list like this

```
<ul>
<li class="bu" data-value="apple">Apple</li>
<li class="bu" data-value="banana">Banana</li>
<li class="bu" data-value="mango">Mango</li>
</ul>
```

after document loaded, I  try to use javascript to get the data-value from all list with bu class to build array

```
var br = document.getElementsByClassName("bu");
for (var i = 0; i < br.length; i++) {
 fruit[i] = this.getAttribute('data-value');}
```

Then I try output by, but no success..

```
alert(fruit);
document.write(fruit);
```

I want to built array like this:

```
var fruit = ["apple", "banana", "mango"];
fruit[1] = "banana"
```

There must be some mistake with javascript, but my level not able to find the mistake yet..

I want to use plain javascript without Jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` does not refer to the item being iterated over inside a `for` loop. While you could fix it by doing

```
fruit[i] = br[i].getAttribute('data-value');
// use push instead if the fruit array is initially empty
```

you could also consider using `Array.from` to construct the array functionally:

```
const fruitArray = Array.from(
  document.getElementsByClassName("bu"), // collection to create the array from
  bu => bu.getAttribute('data-value') // mapper function
);
```

```js
const fruitArray = Array.from(
  document.getElementsByClassName("bu"), // collection to create the array from
  bu => bu.getAttribute('data-value') // mapper function
);
console.log(fruitArray);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="bu" data-value="apple">Apple</li>
  <li class="bu" data-value="banana">Banana</li>
  <li class="bu" data-value="mango">Mango</li>
</ul>
```

`.dataset` is generally supported on browsers IE11 and later, and its syntax is a bit nicer than `getAttribute`, so if you don't have to support ancient browsers, consider using it instead:

```
const fruitArray = Array.from(
  document.getElementsByClassName("bu"),
  bu => bu.dataset.value
);
```

Comment: I tried 'fruit[i] = br[i].getAttribute('data-value');' but it returned 'Uncaught ReferenceError: fruit is not defined'. Anyway, if I use 'Array.from(' it is ok. Can it be cause of my fruit array is initially empty??

Comment: Sounds like you didn't define `fruit` initially - you need `const fruit = []` at the top

Comment: Yes, now try and got it. Solved.